# Create timeseries data - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe of timeseries data which looks like the following;

```
      A  B  C 
1 1   21 32 4
  2   4  2  23
  3   12 9  10
  4   1  56 37
.
.
.
.
  30  63 1  27
  31  32 2  32
.
.
.
12 1  2  3  23
   2  23 1  12
   3  32 3  23
.
.
.
   31 23 2 32
```

It is essentially a multi-index of month and dates with three columns.

I need to turn this into daily data and essentially have a dataframe whereby there is a single index where value in the above dataframe responds to its' respective date over 10 years.

For exmaple;

```
Desired output;
            A  B  C
01/01/2017  21 32 4
.
.
31/12/2017  23 2 32
.
.
01/01/2022  21 32 4
.
.
31/12/2022  23 2 32
```

I hope this is clear! Its essentially turning daily/monthly data into daily/monthly/yearly data.

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame/Series constructor to make your input reproducible?

Comment: how do you chose the year?

Comment: I was looking to do ten years from around 2015 - 2025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.rename(['month', 'day']).to_frame().assign(year=2022))
```

Output:

```
             A   B   C
2022-01-01  21  32   4
2022-01-02   4   2  23
2022-01-03  12   9  10
2022-01-04   1  56  37
2022-01-30  63   1  27
2022-01-31  32   2  32
2022-12-01   2   3  23
2022-12-02  23   1  12
2022-12-03  32   3  23
2022-12-31  23   2  32
```

##### spanning several years

There is no absolute fool proof way to handle years if those are missing. What we can do it to infer the year change when a date goes back in the past and add 1 year in this case:

```
# let's assume the starting year is 2017
date = pd.to_datetime(df.index.rename(['month', 'day']).to_frame().assign(year=2017))

df.index = date + date.diff().lt('0').cumsum().mul(pd.DateOffset(years=1))
```

output:

```
             A   B   C
2017-01-01  21  32   4
2017-01-02   4   2  23
2017-06-03  12   9  10
2017-06-04   1  56  37
2018-01-30  63   1  27 # added 1 year
2018-01-31  32   2  32
2018-12-01   2   3  23
2018-12-02  23   1  12
2018-12-03  32   3  23
2018-12-31  23   2  32
```

used input:

```
        A   B   C
1  1   21  32   4
   2    4   2  23
6  3   12   9  10
   4    1  56  37
1  30  63   1  27 # here we go back from month 1 after month 6
   31  32   2  32
12 1    2   3  23
   2   23   1  12
   3   32   3  23
   31  23   2  32
```

Comment: Thanks! I seem to be getting the following error; ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: day is out of range for month

Comment: @spcol this means you have likely an impossible combination (February 30, April 31, January 0…), you can add `errors='coerce'` to transform those to NaN

Comment: I added an alternative to handle multiple years